# check if hash keys exist in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a big hash and I know that I almost always can get the data I need from `hash['info'][1]['summary_result']['gsb']`. But from time to time these keys may not exist. To avoid an error I use `rescue` like this:

```
begin
  return hash['info'][1]['summary_result']['gsb']
rescue Exception
  return nil
end
```

Are there any shorter methods to do it?

Comment: __Don't__ rescue `Exception`. Always use a more specific class.

Comment: I use ruby 2.1, there is no method `dig`.

Comment: In this case, you can steal [implementation from Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/hash.rb#L534-L541).